# Order of results for `sort` using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I have two equal values for a field. What would be the order of results for `sort` on that field? Random or ordered by insertion date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two documents have equal values for the field you're sorting on, then MongoDB will return the results in the order they are found on disk (ie **Natural order**)

from [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order) :

> **natural order**:
>
> The order in which the database refers to documents on
> disk. This is the default sort order. See $natural and Return in
> Natural Order.

This may coincide with insertion date in some case, but not all of the time (especially when you perform insertion/deletion on your collection), so you should assume that this is random ordering